# ASP.net mvc4 - how to make make user and role anagement

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, authentication

I would like to create small web page using MVC4, for this reason I do not see any reason to make custom authentication and I would like to use already implemented and working authenticate.
My problem is that by default I can not manage users and roles from browser. For this reason I would like to implement my own simple management. Problem is that I dont know how to acces membership tables via entity framework.
When I start application, webform authentification creates tables in my database. After I stop application and create data model for entity framework from my database I get many errors from webform authentification.

So my question is: When I want to access membership data, do I have to use already created models or is there any simple way how can I access it via entity framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that simple. First add Entity Framework using Nuget Packages Console or Managment. Then you should create Model for your Database, smth like:

```
 public class User
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]        
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public long N { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public string Id { get; set; }   
        public string Login { get; set; }    
        public string Password { get; set; }    
        public int AccountRole { get; set; } 
    }
```

Next step is to create Database context :

```
 public class MyDbContext: DbContext, IDisposable where T : class
{
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }        

    public MyDbContext() : base("$DbConnectionString") { }         

    public new void Dispose()
    {
        base.Dispose();            
    }      
}
```

Change $DbConnectionString to your connection string.

But don't store password as a plain text string. Encrypt it.
Then in controller you have to manipulate cookies to assign them if user has authenticated and is recognized as one of your users that are in Users property of your MyDbContext. Check if his AccountRole property has value of Admin and add another portion of cookies. Then you check for this cookies every time this (or any other) user is trying to access secured methods in controller.

P.S.
Also it would be nice to use `IRepository` or even `IRepository<T>` pattern even on a compact project such as yours.

Comment: Thank you, I was alredy doing the same thing, but my problem was that I was using 2 dbcontexts

Comment: Np. Btw it's ok to use two Db Contexts or even more but not two instances of DbContexts. So if you work with let's say instance of DbContext<T> you don't usually instantiate DbContext before you disposed this instance. Many problems lay in a fact that DbContext is not disposed when it should be or disposed before saving anything to Database